# How to round off to 2 decimal places with format SI prefix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, number-formatting

Example in my case:

```
d3.format("~s")(656628); //656.628k
```

But my expected result: 656.63k

I would like used option of d3-format instead of handling it manually.

Live test: https://npm.runkit.com/d3-format

Comment: Is it always going to be a 6 digit number? If so, just do ``d3Format.format("~s")(656628).substring(0, 6) + 'k'``

Comment: @josemartindev 
Oh no.
d3.format("~s")(65662); //65.662k
```
 just do d3Format.format("~s")(656628).substring(0, 6) + 'k'
```
It sem manualy. I think d3-format support to do it.

Comment: The way this is done with significant digits is just strange. I recommend you to do the calculation by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is [`d3.formatPrefix`](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatPrefix), which...

> Convert values to the units of the appropriate SI prefix for the specified numeric reference value before formatting in fixed point notation.

..., with `".2"` as the specifier and your own number as the value.

Here is the demo with your number:

```js
const myNumber = 656628;
console.log(d3.formatPrefix(".2", myNumber)(myNumber));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

That gives you your expected result: `656.63k`.

And, for completeness, some other numbers as well:

```js
[1232, 7676546655, 665, 0.0012, 8887878].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log("Number: " + d + " - Your format: " + d3.formatPrefix(".2", d)(d))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```